# Why is SCIP taking so long and taking so much memory?

Tags: matlab, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, scip

I'm using the SCIP solver in the OPTI toolbox in matlab to solve a quadratic optimization problem with integer constraints. I ran it with the following specs and it's been running for a day and has already taken up 55GB of ram in my system and still counting. I'm new to optimization in matlab, am I doing something wrong or is this usual? I tried with less maxnodes and maxtime, but the program stops with the 'Node limit reached' error in those cases. Here's the code (H, Aeq etc. have been defined earlier in the code) -

```
X = sym('X%d%d', [104 1]);
fun = @(X) 1/2*X'*H*X;
options = optiset('solver', 'SCIP', 'maxnodes', 20000000, 'maxtime', 100000);
Opt = opti('fun', fun, 'eq', Aeq, Beq, 'xtype', xtype, 'options', options);
[xval,fval,exitflag,info] = solve(Opt)
```

Comment: The `X` created in the first line is unused.

Comment: I create the objective function 'fun' using it, and use that function in opti(). How am I supposed to use it?

Comment: The code seems to be working fine for 16x1 X vector and terminates under a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not unusual if the quadratic function(s) are nonconvex.  This easily leads to hard problems that cannot be solved to proven optimality with today's algorithms in any reasonably finite amount of time.  Note that this does not only depend on the size of the problem, but in general smaller problems (of a similar type) will be easier.

This being said, SCIP might already have found a near-optimal solution that is accessible even when the time or node limit is exceeded.